# How to use two array list in Spinner from which data is reflected in grid view on the basis of tag id

Tags: android

I want to reflect all refrigerator items on the basis of tagid,but size of 
`ArrayList` is returning null, `ArrayIndexOutOFBoundException`. I have used  `selectCategory` spinner which is reflecting subcategory name list, parallely I also wants to use `tagid` of selected category to reflect items of category selected in spinner in `Gridview`. I have JSON data like this.

**JSON RESULT:**

```
{
"code": "200",
"action": "success",
"message": "Your request has successfully completed",
"status": "1",
"subcategory_detail": [
    {
        "category_id": "113626",
        "category": "Refrigerators",
        "tag_id": "818415",
        "type_id": "63942",
        "disp_order": "0",
        "shop_id": "7508"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "113627",
        "category": "Air Condition",
        "tag_id": "818416",
        "type_id": "63942",
        "disp_order": "1",
        "shop_id": "7508"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "113628",
        "category": "Kitchen Appliances",
        "tag_id": "818417",
        "type_id": "63942",
        "disp_order": "2",
        "shop_id": "7508"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "113629",
        "category": "Utilities",
        "tag_id": "818418",
        "type_id": "63942",
        "disp_order": "3",
        "shop_id": "7508"
    },
    {
        "category_id": "113634",
        "category": "Washing Machine",
        "tag_id": "818434",
        "type_id": "63942",
        "disp_order": "4",
        "shop_id": "7508"
    }
]
}
```

**OnItemSelectedListener:**

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     str = selectCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
    subcatIdList=new ArrayList<>();
    subcattagidList = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d("categoryidid",""+subcatIdList.size());
    int x=selectCategory.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String y=subcatIdList.get(position+1);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"List ID "+y,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (position == 0)
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("" + category_name);
    }else {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("" + str);
        b = str;

        Toast.makeText(ProductListGridView.this,"b:"+b,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//     new AsyncSearchingTask().execute();
    }

}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

**AsyncTask Class:**

```
class SubCatList extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        UserFunction userFunction = new UserFunction();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.getSubCAtList(category_id);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray("subcategory_detail");
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                        a=post.getString("category_id").toString();
                        b=post.getString("category").toString();
                        c = post.getString("type_id").toString();
                        Log.e("Response categorywise", "" + b);
                        Log.e("Response categoryidwise",""+a);
                        Log.e("Response categorytagid",""+c);
                        subcatIdList.add(a);
                        subcatNameList.add(b);
                        subcattagidList.add(c);

                    }
                }else if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 0){
//                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            Log.d("monacategoryid",""+subcatIdList.size());
            Log.d("monaTagid",""+subcatIdList.size());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "c"+c, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code, what you want to do and how you do and what is problem you are facing.. Your question is not clear..

Comment: I wants to use value of c in spinner to show items in gridview on the basis of tagid which is stored in c.It is returning zero tagid array size if using in spinner.

Comment: value of y is throwing Size of array zero and IndexoutofBoundexception ,Plz help.

Comment: I am using this subcattagidList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subcatNameList);

Comment: check the answer given by Vaibhav.. may it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way,(change in listener)

```
    String itemId ="";
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

      String selValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

      for(int z= 0; z<subcatNameList.size();z++){
           if(selValue.trim().equal(""+subcatNameList.get(z).trim()){
               // do some changes according to 
               itemId = subcattagidList.get(z);
               new callAsukforChanges().execute();
           }
       }

    }
```

I hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)

Comment: Same error is there becz its getting subcatidlist size zero.

Comment: then check your list with debugger. (subcatidlist) size and value

Comment: Error is in  at com.algosoft.zobazar.ProductListGridView.onItemSelected(ProductListGridView.java:170)

Comment: String  itemId = subcattagidList.get(z); line170

Comment: check value of a,b,and c also                                                                                                                                   subcatIdList.add(a);
                        subcatNameList.add(b);
                        subcattagidList.add(c);

Comment: check value of list subcattagidList

Comment: i think, subcattagidList not have value for specific position.